# Not found include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt-creator, filenotfoundexception

So I'm trying to create a dll using QT creator. I went to `new project -> libary -> C++ libary -> choose`. It generated automatically a header file with `global` prefix and a include header that can't be found:

```
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
```

give the error:

> error: QtGlobal: No such file or directory

I find that this header is being included to use `Q_DECL_EXPORT` macro so I searched where this is defined: [`here`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_EXPORT). So I did `#include <QtGlobal>` header but get same error.

What's the source of error and how can I fix this?

Comment: `QTGlobal` and `qglobal.h` are include files from QtCore module, does your `.pro` file have a `QT += core`

Comment: The auto-generated `.pro` file was removing this in this line `QT       -= core gui` just removed `core` from it and it worked

Comment: That's because you choose "C++ library", which is a template for a non-Qt C++ library. It's weird though that the auto-generated header contains Qt includes then...

Comment: Maybe it's a bug? it shouldn't have that line too

Comment: Do not include stuff as `<QtModule/qfoo.h>`. Always include simply as `<QFoo>`, or `<QtGlobal>` in your case.

Comment: Why it does include QT headers then as it isn't a QT project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

The QT creator created the project with the following line in the `.pro` file:

```
 QT -= core gui
```

Note the `-=` operator, this was preventing the linking of `core` library then the not found of `#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>` just removed the `core` from that line and it compiled fine.

Comment: It's not a bug. You created a non-Qt project. It's not supposed to link to any Qt libraries, or to use any Qt headers! You got exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I am linking QtCore with the line `QT += core sql network` but I still get this error. In QtCreator, I can follow the link to the include file so it seems like it finds it but still I am getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add the following to your `*.pro` file:

```
QT += core
```

Answer (score 0):

The QT creator created the project with the following line in the .pro file:
I had to remove/commented using # the whole line below

```
# QT -= core gui
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a QTDIR to the system environment variable ,restart VS and refer to $(QTDIR) in the VS project configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VZS3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryxnu.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please develop your answer and improve the formatting? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer